# JSP calling function from front-end

Tags: jsp

Hi there I've successfully setup a function in JSP can calling it from the same file.
I want to separate my logic from presentation, how would I go about throwing this function <%! somewhere else in a class and then accessing it from my .jsp front-end file>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must have to avoid Java code in JSP files. Take a look at - [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) You need to place (create and compile) a public class definition under the `WEB-INF/classes`. For instance,

```
package test;

public class Foo
{
  public void methodOne() { .. }
  public static void methodTwo() { .. }
}
```